# On the convexity of $-\int_0^t\Re\frac{\eta' \left( 1/2+ix \right) }{\eta \left( 1/2+ix \right) }dx,$ for $t>0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, convex-analysis, dirichlet-series

Let for $\Re s>0$ $$\eta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^{s}}$$ the [Dirichlet eta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function). After I read  *Example 5* and *Corollary 9* from [1], I've asked myself an analogue

> **Question.** If I define for $t\in \left( 0,\infty \right) $ (our $x$ inside the integral is thus a positive real) $$f(t):=-\int_0^t\Re\frac{\eta' \left( \frac{1}{2}+ix \right) }{\eta \left( \frac{1}{2}+ix \right) }dx,$$
>   a) is it well-defined?, and  b) what's about the convexity of this function  for $t\in \left( 0,\infty \right) $?

Since I know the calculations of professors in [1] to get such the analogue in which I was inspired, then as an answer for b) if you want only is required the key hint to study/deduce what's about the convexity ($f''(t)\geq 0$, $\forall t>0$) of our $f(t)$. **Many thanks.**

Was fixed a **typo** concerning the condition to be convex.

---

References:

[1] Arias de Reyna and Van de Lune, *On the exact location of the non-trivial zeros of Riemann's Zeta function*, Acta Arithmetica 163.3 (2014).

Comment: Since $n^{1/2+ix}$ is not well defined, $\eta(1/2+ix)$ is not well defined either.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Since $\eta(1/2+ix)$ is defined using Wikipedia's identity, say that is summable @SimpleArt isn't? Many thanks.

Comment: Well, the above definition you have given requires one to calculate $n^{1/2+ix}$.  How do you define that?

Comment: I belive that I am wrong in my previous comment, Wikipedia said that is convergent for $\Re s>0$, and Abel summable on the complex plane, but I don't know what it is? Many thanks @SimpleArt

Comment: Your example is a complex number, well defined @SimpleArt

Comment: @SimpleArt Why do you believe that $n^{1/2+ix}=e^{(1/2+ix)\log(n)}$ is not well-defined?  We assume the principal branch for the logarithm here.

Comment: @Dr.MV Just to be careful.

Comment: You may wish to see that $\eta(s)=(1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s)$, where $\zeta(s)$ is the [Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function), and more information can be found concerning the Wiki for the [Riemann hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis).

Comment: I believe tha is a great idea, to use such relationship, the first identity that you say I believe that is the key. Many thanks @SimpleArt

Comment: Many thanks for your attention and contribution from your identities, I hope that in next hours I obtain an answer @SimpleArt

Comment: Notice that

$$\int\Re\frac{\eta'(1/2+ix)}{\eta(1/2+ix)}dx=\Re\int\frac{\eta'(1/2+ix)}{\eta(1/2+ix)}dx=\Re i\log\left[\eta(1/2+ix)\right]=-\arg\left[\eta(1/2+ix)\right]$$

Comment: While not an answer, the following puts some good intuition that this is true: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arg(dirichlet+eta(1%2F2%2Bix))

Comment: You have to be careful here. $\eta'/\eta$ has many poles on $Re(s) = 1/2$, so $\int_0^t \frac{\eta'}{\eta}(1/2+ix)dx$ can be defined only as a principal value. And in that case yes $\int_0^t \frac{\eta'}{\eta}(1/2+ix)dx = -\text{arg} (\eta(1/2+ix))$ with the branch of $\text{arg}[\eta(s)]$ continuous (and monotone) on $Re(s) = 1/2$ and $\text{arg}( \eta(1/2)) =0$. Anyway this is mainly a tautology. @SimpleArt

Comment: Many thanks for your contribution, mathematics from SimleArt and from you are good @user1952009 If you can add an answer, also explaining how one define our function as a principal value, with branch of its argument continuous and monotone, it is the best.

Comment: I'd imagine you should Google that a bit.

Comment: You say search for more information about the last comment of user1952009, not about the question in general. Isn't? Many thanks for patience and attention @SimpleArt I have books about complex analysis and Riemann Zeta.

Comment: Yes, some of those terms should be easy enough to find.

Comment: It is exactly the same as $\int \mathfrak{R} \frac{\sinh(x)}{\cosh(x)}dx$